# Save data from api (but just once)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, api, validation, rails-activerecord

I would like to save the data from the API, but just once. Currently it's saving data each time I reload my page, so I have the same entry lot of times... I just want to save new one if they are.
When I try to add validation to avoid this I get this error :

> Validation failed: Date has already been taken, Url has already been taken

This is my code :

schema :

```
 create_table "conferences", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "title",      null: false
  t.string   "url"
  t.date     "date",       null: false
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

conference.rb:

```
class Conference < ActiveRecord::Base
validates_presence_of :title, :date
validates :date, :url, :uniqueness => true

 def self.save_conference_from_api
  response = ApiMeetup.new.events('parisrb')
  api_data = JSON.parse(response.body)
  parisrb = []
  api_data.each do |event|
    if event["name"] == "ParisRb.new(premier: :mardi, pour: :talks)"
      parisrb << event
    end
  end
  parisrb.map do |line|
    conference = Conference.new
    conference.title = line['name']
    conference.date = line['time']
    conference.url = line['link']
    conference.save!
  end
  Conference.all
 end
end
```

conferences_controller :

```
def index
  @conferences = Conference.save_conference_from_api
end
```

index :

```
%ul
  - @conferences.each do |conf|
    %li
      %span
        = conf.date
```

Comment: Your validations are working fine so what exactly is the problem? They are preventing the records being created and telling you.

Comment: Yes the validation works, but I can not access to the site then. So how can I say "ok its exist so do nothing and go check the next one, then after all display the page"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't save it if it's not valid

```
conference.save!
```

becomes

```
if conference.valid? conference.save!
```

Because save! raises an ActiveRecordValidation error then you could trap that instead and you don't really need the ! on the save method if you are checking for a valid record before saving

So you could have

```
begin
  conference.save!
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => invalid
  # Do nothing
end
```

Or you really should have

```
if conference.valid? conference.save
```

If all records are in an array then your html template can iterate through the array and present the errors for each one if you wanted.

Comment: @Orsay You are welcome. You didn't get a very quick response because your question was very unclear. If you spend a lot more time thinking things through before posting your question in the furture you will get better/faster responses. Glad to be of help

Comment: Yes I keep trying posting clearer questions :) Thank you for help and advice !